# Local constants in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, constants

Is it possible to declare not changeble local value in method, like constant or read-only property. 
The goal is protect value from casual changing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Readonly local variable in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412736/readonly-local-variable-in-vb-net)

Comment: @AlexB ok, you're right. Thank you!